# Using a Materialized View, can you generate a Two-Timestamp view from a One-Timestamp table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, data-warehouse, ddl, materialized-views

This question is about the Two-Timestamp tables in the style of Kimball dimensions, but not necessarily following a full star schema / snowflake scheme. Just think simple START_DATE_TIME and END_DATE_TIME to describe the validity of some record over time.

If you start with a table with ONLY a "start timestamp", is it possible to produce a two-timestamp Materialized View, and have it efficiently (incrementally) refreshed?

For discussion purposes assume a recent version of Microsoft SQL Server will be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No this isn't possible with SQL Server indexed views (indexing is the materialized view mechanism in SQL Server)

There are [very many limitations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191432.aspx) on constructs they may contain and self joins, sub queries, and tne OVER clause/ranking/aggregate window functions are all listed among these.

This last restriction rules out using `Lag` and `Lead` etc to get the next timestamp and without window functions you would still bump into one of the other restrictions listed above trying to do this.

Comment: Thanks. Exactly what I didn't want to hear but was afraid I would :)